# Is it possible to get the html contents until the program find a specific comments in php?

Tags: php

I am trying to get the string until the program find a comments. I tried to use preg_match function but it gives me a number only. I thought getting the position would be helpful too as I can cut the texts using that position. 
This is what I tried

```
$text='<div dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;" trbidi="on">
    <b>sdffsdf</b><br />
    <!--more--><h1>Contents after the more comments</h1></div>';

$pattern='<!--more-->';
preg_match($pattern, $text, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
print_r($matches);
```

I want to get the texts before the `<!--more-->` comment is found so the expected result would be

```
<div dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;" trbidi="on">
<b>sdffsdf</b><br />
```

Any idea how can I achieve it? 
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

OK guys I got the my answer. I need to use preg_split function :). Posting the answer as it may help others

```
$text='<div dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;" trbidi="on">
    <b>sdffsdf</b><br /><i>so this is more contents</i>
    <!--more--><h1>Contents after the more comments</h1></div>';


$words = preg_split('(<!--more-->)', $text);
//print_r($words[0]);
echo $words[0];
echo "<br>";
echo $words[1];
```